# stack oftype<> option how to work

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone tell me how to use `stack.ofType<>`? I have tried many times but can't do this.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stack st = new Stack();
    st.Push("joginder");
    st.Push("singh");
    st.Push("banger");
    st.Push("Kaithal");
    st.OfType<>  //how to work this option
}
```

Comment: It is not clear, what you're trying to do.

Comment: You're only inserting strings in your stack, so the benefits `OfType<>()` would bring you are not clear. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `generics` and `Stack<T>`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stack<string> st = new Stack<string>();
        st.Push("joginder");
        st.Push("singh");
        st.Push("banger");
        st.Push("Kaithal");
 }
```

You could also do:

```
public class Client {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Stack<Client> st = new Stack<Client>();
        st.Push(new Client { "joginder" });
        st.Push(new Client { "singh" });
        st.Push(new Client { "banger" });

}
```

Note the class Client is to demonstrate how `T` is replaced for the type you assign.

Answer (score 4):

Use the generic `Stack<T>` type instead of `Stack`, that way you will get a stack of the specific type, and you don't have to cast the values that you read from it:

```
Stack<string> st = new Stack<string>();
st.Push("joginder");
st.Push("singh");
st.Push("banger");
st.Push("Kaithal");
```

Now when you pop something from the stack, or loop through the items, it will be a string already, and you don't have to cast it.

Answer (score 1):

You provide a type like so

```
st.OfType<string>()
```

This returns an IEnumerable for you to iterate without popping any items off the stack.

Given this code:

```
        Stack st = new Stack();
        st.Push("joginder");
        st.Push("singh");
        st.Push("banger");
        st.Push("Kaithal");
        st.Push(1);
        st.Push(1.0);

        foreach (var name in st.OfType<string>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
```

you will get this output:

```
 joginder
 singh
 banger
 Kaithal
```

Comment: thanks for share you valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx, but, basically you can use the OfType to create an IEnumerable of items of that specific type, so, for instance if your code read:

```
        Stack st = new Stack();
        st.Push("joginder");
        st.Push(1.4);
        st.Push("singh");
        st.Push("banger");
        st.Push(2.8); 
        st.Push("Kaithal");

        IEnumerable<String> strings = st.OfType<String>();  //how to work this option
        IEnumerable<double> doubles = st.OfType<double>();
```

will create to "lists", one containing all the strings in the Stack, and one containing all the doubles.